# Why doesn't AWS Powertools & Middy capture DDB tracing from my Node Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, trace

I'm trying to capture the trace from my Node Lambda to DynamoDB, but it's only capturing header. Currently using the aws powertool & middy, but it doesn't seem to capture it. Am I missing something?

I'm following this instructions: https://docs.powertools.aws.dev/lambda/typescript/latest/core/tracer/#lambda-handler

```
import { Tracer, captureLambdaHandler } from '@aws-lambda-powertools/tracer';
import middy from '@middy/core';
 
const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
const dynamodb = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);
const table_name = process.env.TABLE_NAME;
 
const tracer = new Tracer({ serviceName: 'serverlessAirline' });
....

// Wrap the handler with middy
export const handler = middy(lambdaHandler)
 
// Use the middleware by passing the Tracer instance as a parameter
.use(captureLambdaHandler(tracer));
```

Code: https://pastebin.com/WTis4vGX
Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/623R3fU